# How to get smarty value in tpl file - cs cart?

Tags: php, cs-cart

I'm trying to get smarty value in my profile_account.tpl file.

```
{capture name="profile_pic"}{$user_data.main_pair.icon.image_path}{/capture}
```

How can I get this in `top_quick_links.tpl`?

```
"$smarty.capture.profile_pic"
```

But that doesn't return any value. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you did not assign the `$user_data` array for the template engine.
Your solution is not so elegant. I suggest you to put this into your controller file:

This is the way to assign custom variable for Smarty in CS-Cart

```
Registry::get("view")->assign("user_profile_picture", $user_data['main_pair']['icon']['image_path']);
```

And use this variable directly in the .tpl file:

```
<img src="{$user_profile_picture}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code for 4.x versions:

```
{$smarty.capture.profile_pic nofilter}
```